# Civi entity didn't automatically create the table in database

Tags: civicrm-entity

I created a new entity for my extension. These are the steps i followed:

1. Generated the skeletal files using civix generate:entity command
2. Edited the XML schema definitions as i needed.
3. Generate your DAO and SQL files using civix generate:entity-boilerplate command.
4. Generated the database upgrader.

After following these steps i found the 'auto_install.sql' has the sql query to create the table in DB. But when i uninstall the extension and reinstall it again it didn't created the table.

I even executed the sql query manually it works fine but when i reinstall it, it doesn't create the table.. what could be the reason?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you check extension has Upgrader.php and Upgrader/Base.php?

Comment: @PradeepNayak yes it has. do i need to do any modification in it?

Comment: Its under correct directory?

Comment: yes..but i didn't define any functions on it yet

Comment: @PradeepNayak could you please help me with this?

Comment: What is set as 'namespace' in your extension info.xml and what is the full path of Upgrader.php? Are both same? Can you check the permission of sql/auto_install.sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111982/discussion-between-safron-and-pradeep-nayak).